# How to display saved item in combo box in edit mode of MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have simple combo box in create View. After saving the data, when I go to edit mode, I want to show saved the item in the combo box. Below is the code of the combo-box in the create view:

```html
<select>
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Vendor</option>
  <option value="1">Jindal Ltd</option>
  <option value="2">ABC Enterprise</option>
  <option value="3">Sun Manufacture</option>
</select>
```

Screenshot of the create form.

[image]

Now, what code should I write in controller and in view, so I can show the saved item in the combo box?

Here is the screen shot of edit mode, I want to display the saved item in the combo box.

[image]

Comment: You need to set it in your model and use model based view. Where is your controller & view code?

Comment: The code from your view is just pure HTML, it doesn't have any ASP.NET MVC structure. You need to add your controller and view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to set the selected value something like following. Also as @Guillelon said we are not able to see the view code completely, it would be easy for us to see how your view looks like and suggest an answer.

Following example is plain html.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").val("2");
    });
</script>
</div>
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">Test1</option>
    <option value="2">Test2</option>
    <option value="3">Test3</option>
</select>
```

If you are using a strongly typed Model it would look something like following.

```
@model MVC3Stack.Models.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").val('@Model.SelectedValue');
    });
</script>
</div>
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">Test1</option>
    <option value="2">Test2</option>
    <option value="3">Test3</option>
</select>
```

And one more example

Index Action Method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyModel mod = new MyModel {  SelectedValue=2 };
    return View(mod);
}
```

And the view

```
@model MVC3Stack.Models.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value="1", Text="test1" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "test2" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "test3" });

}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</div>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, lst);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... I will try to add it... I was confused about the combo box thing...why its so complicated ? What if I have a list which comes from DB and I want to show it in edit mode ?

Comment: That's not an issue. The list I showed you was just an example. If you get a list from the database you just need to convert it into `List<SelectListItem>` and pass it on as the second parameter to the `DropDownListFor()` helper.